# Cross application communication in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to add two dropdown list controls to a page using **javascript** so they could work as a **cascading dropdown list** (filter option based on selected values). The problem is that they will be rendered in different parts of a page, so I cannot use a parent component for them. I also need to use React component for both of these controls.
I assume it would be two React apps, since there's no way to manualy start application on some random html tag like I used to in Angular with *angular.bootstrap* function.
Is there a way to make one React app to listen to events in another app? Or maybe to DOM changes that other app producing?

Comment: What's your definition of an "app"? Do you mean that the two components should be *declared* in separate files, or should actually be *loaded* separately in runtime?

Comment: Actually they can be declared in a same file, but still they'll be rendered in different parts of a page. So there will be no parent component for them

Comment: Ok, so two components mounted separately using `ReactDOM.render()` need to communicate. Theoretically, as long as you have a store that is available globally, both could subscribe to it. For example, It's possible for multiple "apps" to share a Redux store (even though not recommended, AFAIK).